# Can I write a smoothly running snake game with Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

Just for fun I tried to implement the classical snake game in Python/Tkinter. It feels very laggy and I'm not quite sure, whether I can fix that or not. I try to give a short outline of the program:

I first build up the canvas and I add an event handler for each arrow key:

```
root = self.root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, width = width, height = height)
canvas.pack()
canvas.bind("<Left>", on_left) # on_left is a very short function
```

I also have a function for the timestep. It paints the graphics and will schedule itself to be called again. The function is not very efficient, as it redraws 100 rectangles every time:

```
def timestep(self):
    # draw the graphics here (about 100 filled rectangles)
    timer = threading.Timer(interval, timestep)
    timer.start()
```

Now, I have two problems:

- Even when I choose the `interval` in `timestep()` around 0.05 (equivalent to 20 frames per second), I do not get more than maybe 3-5 Frames per second.
- It seems that control input from the keyboard is delayed by about 0.5 seconds.

I wonder about three things:

- Is it possible at all to write a smooth, non-lagging (20 fps) snake with Tkinter canvas when you want to draw 100 rectangles every time step?
- Is `threading.Timer` the right choice to call the timestep function?
- Why do my keyboard inputs seem to be delayed?

Comment: If you are not using canvas.delete(...) between each frame you have a memory leak.  

100 rectangles is only 200 triangles,  (not that many, gaming engines can do millions at 60+ fps)

Comment: May I ask why you're creating 100 rectangles with each step?

Comment: And `self.parent.after(interval, timestep)` is probably simpler and easier. Can you show just enough code for the issue to be reproducible?

Comment: You don't need threads. There are many examples of animation on this site using the `after` method

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The existing answer do not exactly describe how I could finally solve the problem, so I will give an answer to my own question here:

The main problem is that functions like `canvas.create_rectangle(...)` will actually add a new rectangle on every call. So you will run into performance issues because you have too many rectangles even after a very short while.

You can use `canvas.delete(...)` to delete some or all rectangles. If you delete all existing rectangles and create new rectangles in each timestep, performance is ok, but the screen flickers.

The best way is to create the rectangles once on initialization and then to just change their color in each timestep:

```
# on startup:
rect[x][y] = canvas.create_rectangle(...)

# in each timestep
canvas.itemconfig(rect[x][y], fill = myColor)
```

With that I get good performance and no flicker, even though I still change the color of 100 rectangles 20 times per second.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the builtin `canvas.after(funciton,interval)` instead of the threading.timer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using canvas.delete(...) between each frame you have a memory leak.

Comment: This shouldn't be a problem until OP's machine hits its max memory. It sounds like the low framerate occurs immediately.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: the canvas has known perfotmance problems with very large numbers of objects. Creating 2000 rectangles per second will start to hit that wall pretty quickly, well before the system runs out of memory.  That's not the only problem but it's definitely _a_ problem

Comment: Keep them down votes coming, I'm just here to try and help people.

Comment: @kpie: if you want up votes, write better answers. A one line answer usually won't get many votes.  Plus, this answer doesn't answer the question sufficiently, which is probably why it was downvoted. Instead of writing a second one-line answer, try to improve this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a smooth running game with many objects on the screen, and you can do so without threads. Though, that depends on how you define "smooth" and "many", and it is dependent on how you implement it.

If you have an algorithm that deletes and recreates everything in the scene on every iteration, it will run very slowly. The proper way to do animation is to create the objects that you want to animate once, and only once. Then, for each frame you can reconfigure or move them with the canvas methods `itemconfigure`, `move` and `coords`.

I've seen this work fine with hundreds of items on a canvas. It starts to bog down if you have thousands, however. Also, the canvas has a known performance issue when you create thousands of items, even if you delete old items.

So, like with many performance related questions, it partly comes down to the final algorithm. For example, in a snake game you could choose to redraw the whole snake on every frame, or you can look at the problem and realize you only have to move one or two segments of the snake. The first method will be slow, the second one will be very fast.

The bottom line is that the tkinter canvas is powerful enough to smoothly animate perhaps a few dozen items at one time when implemented with the proper algorithm.